# How do I get Java graphic location information?

Tags: java, graph, awt, java-2d

How do I get Java graphic location information? do I get the location information of the 2D object that I created? I created the object as follows. I need the location information of these objects.

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
     //backGround
     g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
     g.fillRect(1, 1, 400, 400);

     //left object
     g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(Pxi, Pyi, 20, 20);

    //right object
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillRect(Pxs, Pys, 20, 20);

    g.dispose();

 }
```

`g.fillRect (Pxs, Pys, 20, 20)` I need the location information of these objects.

Comment: DYM the location on-screen? `Pxs, Pys` gives that. The location in memory? No object is put into memory. Something else? ..

Comment: global variables pxs and pys. I can share the whole code if you want.

Comment: *"I can share the whole code if you want."* No, I don't want you dumping the entire code here. If more code is needed, make it a [mre]. But neither the whole code nor an MRE will answer the questions I asked. Answer this question **first**: What exactly do you mean by 'location'? Please pay attention & read carefully, I should not have to ask twice.

Comment: I need to know where it's in the frame.

Comment: The location relative to the frame? (Why? What is the point of knowing that? See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)) or relative to the container it is being drawn in? (As mentioned earlier, that is already known according to the values of `Pxs, Pys`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20) you draw colored rectangle into your screen (I mean Canvas or JPanel) at x and y position. In your case Pxs and Pys coordinates of drawing in user space.
I think you should read this to understand more about Java2D API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/coordinate.html